# angularjs call to an external url with $http.get

Tags: angularjs, json

I have a problem with angular and calls to an external json, the fact is that local works perfectly, but when I make the call with a full url gives me 404, I leave the code in case you see something missing, thanks:

```
// JavaScript Document
var angularTodo = angular.module('lostsysApp', []);

function mainController($scope, $http) {
    $scope.names = [];

    $http.get('http://www.viudadesoubrier.com/angular/model.php')
        .success(function(data) {
            $scope.names = eval(data);
            console.log(data)
        })
        .error(function(data) {
            alert(data);
            console.log('Error: ' + data);
        });

    $scope.addNom = function() {
        $http.post('http://www.viudadesoubrier.com/angular/model.php', { op: 'append', nom: $scope.nom, telefon: $scope.telefon } )
            .success(function(data) {
                $scope.names = eval(data);
                console.log(data)
            })
            .error(function(data) {
                console.log('Error: ' + data);
            });

        $scope.nom="";
        $scope.telefon="";
    }

    $scope.delNom = function( nom ) {
        if ( confirm("Seguro?") ) {
            $http.post('http://www.viudadesoubrier.com/angular/model.php', { op: 'delete', nom: nom } )
                .success(function(data) {
                    $scope.names = eval(data);
                    console.log(data)
                })
                .error(function(data) {
                    console.log('Error: ' + data);
                });
        }
    }
}
```

Add the code of index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="lostsysApp">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-beta.11/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="app.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="mainController">
        <div class="jumbotron text-center">
            <h1>Angular Test</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 text-center">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" ng-model="nom" placeholder="Contact Name" class="form-control input-lg text-center" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" ng-model="telefon" placeholder="Phone Number" class="form-control input-lg text-center" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" ng-click="addNom()">Añadir</button>
            </div>

            <div ng-repeat="n in names">
                <p>
                    {{n.nom}} ({{n.phone}})
                    <a href="#" ng-click="delNom(n.nom)">[X]</a>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried hitting that url in your browser? Do you get a 404 then? I would expect you to get cross origin issues though too.

Comment: I'm not sure that it is deal of code. Could you share more info how you published your server? Could you hit the site with any request generator without your angular client?

Comment: I put a fake url in the post. The url works fine the response is a normal JSON: http://www.viudadesoubrier.com/angular/model.php.

Comment: Can you provide what you see in the dev tools > network in the request and the response?

Comment: I get  "error undefined"

Comment: is CORS enabled from your server side? since you are making request from one domain to another, you need to enable CORS. I tried your code, I am getting "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource" error

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**controller :**

```
var angularTodo = angular.module('lostsysApp', []);    


        angularTodo.controller('mainController', function($scope, $http) {
            $scope.names = [];

            $http.get('http://www.viudadesoubrier.com/angular/model.php')
                .success(function(data) {
                    $scope.names = eval(data);
                    console.log(data)
                })
                .error(function(data) {
                    alert(data);
                    console.log('Error: ' + data);
                });

            $scope.addNom = function() {
                $http.post('http://www.viudadesoubrier.com/angular/model.php', { op: 'append', nom: $scope.nom, telefon: $scope.telefon } )
                    .success(function(data) {
                        $scope.names = eval(data);
                        console.log(data)
                    })
                    .error(function(data) {
                        console.log('Error: ' + data);
                    });

                $scope.nom="";
                $scope.telefon="";
            }

            $scope.delNom = function( nom ) {
                if ( confirm("Seguro?") ) {
                    $http.post('http://www.viudadesoubrier.com/angular/model.php', { op: 'delete', nom: nom } )
                        .success(function(data) {
                            $scope.names = eval(data);
                            console.log(data)
                        })
                        .error(function(data) {
                            console.log('Error: ' + data);
                        });
                }
            }
        });
```

Enable CORS from server side

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```